# Kivy roundish menu

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to write a roundish menu with Kivy. At the end it should somehow look like this:

[image]

I've stumbled upon some problems at the early beginnings. I already created the "mainmenu"-button (0.1). Now I wanted to create 2 new menu-circles 2.1 + 2.2. The problem is that the events for the two new buttons occur when I click on the main-button but nothing happens by clicking on the new buttons.
I really appreciate any help. :)

**menu.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

class menuApp(App):
    print "test"
    def secTouch(self):
        print "sectouch"


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
pass


class Menu (FloatLayout):
def newMenu(self):
    dynamicMenu = Factory.First()
    self.add_widget(dynamicMenu)
    pass

class First(Scatter):

    def firstTouch(self):
        dynamicWidget = Factory.Second()
        self.add_widget(dynamicWidget)    
    print "touch"
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menuApp().run()
```

**menu.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
#: set buttonSize 100, 100
#: set middleOfScreen 0,0

RootWidget:
<RootWidget>:
    Menu

<Menu>
    on_touch_down: root.newMenu()

<First>:
    id: first
    pos: root.size[0]/2-self.size[0]/2, root.size[1]/2-self.size[1]/2
    size: 100, 100
size_hint: None, None
Widget:
    on_touch_down: root.firstTouch()
    id: me
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    pos: root.size[0]/2-self.size[0]/2, root.size[1]/2-self.size[1]/2

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Ellipse:
            pos: me.pos
            size: buttonSize


<Second@Scatter>:
pos: root.size[0]/2-self.size[0]/2+40, root.size[1]/2-self.size[1]/2+40
size: 100, 100
size_hint: None, None
on_touch_down: app.secTouch()
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: 1, 0, 0
    Ellipse:
        pos: root.size[0]/2-self.size[0]/2+40, root.size[1]/2-self.size[1]/2+40
        size: buttonSize
```

Answer (score 2):

Every touch event is dispatched to the `on_touch_down` event handlers, not just touches in a given area (within the widget). Each time you touch the screen, regardless of where, the `Menu`s `on_touch_down` is fired. You should use `collide_point()` to ensure the touch is within the given boundaries.

The [Grabbing Touch Events](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#grabbing-touch-events) section of the Kivy guide has an example of `collide_point()`, as well as some more info about touch events in general.

But, the basic idea:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        # do stuff here
        return True  # 'handle' the event so it will not propagate
```